# CakePHP 3.0 Associations not displaying displayField from another model

Tags: cakephp, associations

So I have a Users table and a Security Questions table. I am able to create a user with an associated security question, but when I view the profile I cannot get the displayField to show properly.

Here is my code for the UsersTable.php

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('users');
    $this->displayField('email');
    $this->primaryKey('id');
    $this->hasOne('SecurityQuestions',
        [ 'foreignKey' => 'security_question_id']);

    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
}
```

Here is the code for the SecurityQuestionsTable.php

```
    public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('security_questions');
    $this->displayField('question');
    $this->primaryKey('security_question_id');

    $this->hasMany('Users', ['foreignKey'=>'security_question_id', 'bindingKey'=>'security_question_id']);
    $this->belongsTo('SecurityQuestions', [
        'foreignKey' => 'security_question_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
}
```

Here is my UsersController.php view method:

```
    public function view($id = null)
{
    $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
        'contain' => []
    ]);

    $this->set('user', $user);
    $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
}
```

Last but not least, the view code

```
<h3><?= h($user->id) ?></h3>
<table class="vertical-table">
    <tr>
        <th><?= __('Email') ?></th>
        <td><?= h($user->email) ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><?= __('Password') ?></th>
        <td><?= h($user->password) ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><?= __('First Name') ?></th>
        <td><?= h($user->first_name) ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><?= __('Last Name') ?></th>
        <td><?= h($user->last_name) ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><?= __('Id') ?></th>
        <td><?= $this->Number->format($user->id) ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><?= __('Created') ?></th>
        <td><?= h($user->created) ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><?= __('Expiration') ?></th>
        <td><?= h($user->expiration) ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><?= __('User Status') ?></th>
        <td><?= h($user->user_status) ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><?= __('Security Question') ?></th>
        <td><?= h($user->security_question_id) ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><?= __('Security Question Answer') ?></th>
        <td><?= h($user->security_question_answer) ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am fairly new to CakePHP.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of small things you need to change.

In your UsersTable:

```
$user = $this->Users->get($id, [
    'contain' => []
]);
```

needs to be

```
$user = $this->Users->get($id, [
    'contain' => ['SecurityQuestions']
]);
```

And in your view file:

```
<tr>
    <th><?= __('Security Question') ?></th>
    <td><?= h($user->security_question_id) ?></td>
</tr>
```

needs to be

```
<tr>
    <th><?= __('Security Question') ?></th>
    <td><?= h($user->security_question->question) ?></td>
</tr>
```

The display field is mainly used to create a drop-down lists, and by some plugins that build scaffolded views (Like [crud-view](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/crud-view)).

Comment: Hii Dakota, can you please explain what the last code is doing in `$user->security_question->question`. I need a similar help [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671622/cakephp-3-display-title-from-other-table)